# android load content for all tabs when app starts

Tags: java, android

My app has a tabHost that handles 5 tabs that loads properly their activities. However, app starts with tab1 selected and tab2 and following ones are not loaded until user click into related tab! How could I previously load content to other tabs before its selection? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can't preload an Activity. But you could put all the views in the same activity. I use TabHost in some of my apps and you can simply define the different tab content in the xml. This way you don't have to start a new activity for each tab and everything gets created at once!

Depending on what kind of application you are developing, this could be a solution.

Answer (score 1):

I can't find a direct way to load all the tabs but this approach seems to work well. If you have, say three tabs and want them to load all at once, set the current tab to the last tab and work your way to the tab you want showing as below. Each tab is loaded and the last tab is the one showing.

```
// Adding all TabSpec to TabHost
tabHost.addTab( tab0 );
tabHost.addTab( tab1 );
tabHost.addTab( tab2 );


// Preload tabs
tabHost.setCurrentTab( 2 );
tabHost.setCurrentTab( 1 );
tabHost.setCurrentTab( 0 );
```